# Windows 10 won't show password prompt after sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep

Windows 10 Pro 64-bits, up-to-date.

This happens sometimes but I lost big amount of unsaved work not once, and even but not so important game progress because of this problem.

Sometimes when my computer goes to sleep, when it comes back, the login prompt won't appear as hard as I try. It just shows the background:

[image]

Here's a video demonstration of the problem:
https://youtu.be/RkGQ-V81RDA

Comment: I am having a very similar problem.  Any luck?

Comment: @fyrepenguin I turned off sleeping after inactive time. Didn't see this happening anymore, not sure if because my computer is not sleeping as often as before or if some update fixed it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is my laptop, and I need it to be able to properly wake after sleeping.  I will have to keep looking then.